# Python installation in chroot fails

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, anaconda, chroot

I need to install `Miniconda` Python in a chroot:

```
chroot $chroot_dir wget -q https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-3.9.1-Linux-x86_64.sh -O /tmp/miniconda.sh                                                                                    
chroot $chroot_dir chmod +x /tmp/miniconda.sh
chroot $chroot_dir /tmp/miniconda.sh -f -b -p /opt/conda
```

But the installation is incomplete and I get:

```
/opt/conda/pkgs/python-3.4.2-0/bin/python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.4m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
cannot execute native linux-64 binary, output from 'uname -a' is:
```

If I boot the finalized image and run the commands manually, I can install Miniconda with no problems.

**Is there some problem with the chroot commands? How do I fix this?**

*FYI*: The chroot environment is created with `vmbuilder` (ie. `debootstrap`):

```
vmbuilder kvm ubuntu -o -v --suite precise --arch amd64 --rootsize 9216 --user username --pass password --hostname $dname --addpkg libjson-perl --addpkg liburi-encode-perl --addpkg curl --addpkg acpid --addpkg openssh-server --addpkg wordpress --addpkg memcached --addpkg php5-memcache --addpkg nfs-common --addpkg dmidecode --addpkg unzip --addpkg mysql-server --addpkg libstring-shellquote-perl --tmpfs - --domain mydomain.com --ip 10.1.1.2 --execscript="./$me"
```

Comment: 32 bit works? did you try? looks like you are using 32 bit linux

Comment: @pbu Look at the `vmbuilder` command, I specify `--arch amd64`.

Comment: where is this libpython3.4m.so.1.0 located? you will need to put that path  instead of /usr/local/lib  and run  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`

Comment: @pbu But how do I do this with my `chroot` commands? Could you create an answer?

Comment: @pbu Inside the chroot the file seems to be in `/opt/conda/pkgs/python-3.4.2-0/lib/libpython3.4m.so.1.0`.

Comment: `chroot sh /chroot/sbin/ldconfig /opt/conda/pkgs/python-3.4.2-0/lib/  /usr/lib /usr/local/lib`